# How do I save the first text in a textbox and not overwrite it C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, textbox, clipboard

I am working on a very basic project where I can copy something to the clipboard and it saves it in a RichTextBox in my application. I've made it loop through and check the clipboard every 0.5 seconds with a timer but how do I make the first copy stay in the TextBox because what it does now is:

```
-I copy something to the clipboard
-It sends it to the TextBox
-When I copy something else it overwrites it
```

How do I make them add one after the other?

This is what I got so far;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CBR
{
    public partial class mainFrm : Form
    {
        public mainFrm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void mainFrm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void clipboardUpdater_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: richTextBox1.Text += Clipboard.GetText();

Comment: I've tried that, and what happends is that the same clipboard gets copied every 0.5 seconds, maybe I need to make the timer update only if there is something new, but how would I do tha is a new question hehe

Comment: You can save in other variable what are you saving, and if it is not equal, yo do the `richTextBox1.Text += Clipboard.GetText();` thing... do you get it ?

Comment: I dont quite understand what you mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like this is what you're looking for;

```
    private void clipboardUpdater_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!richTextBox1.Text.Contains(Clipboard.GetText()))
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += Clipboard.GetText();
        }
    }
```

If you want to seperate each paste, replace the statement with this;

`richTextBox1.Text += " " + Clipboard.GetText();`

Comment: Yes! That worked perfectly, I kinda understand but not fully, sorry if you dont have to explain but maybe someone will.. so "!" means that if its true right?

Comment: @ChristofferNilsson Adding a ! means "not." So in this case, if the RichTextBox.Text property does **not** contain what is in the ClipBoard, add it to the property.

Comment: Oooh! That makes so much sense! I would never have figured out that I could add .Contain to it, does it work with all .Text? like could I do something like this..

if(!Textbox2.Text.Contain(textbox3))
{
  Do something
}

Comment: @ChristofferNilsson Absolutely. It works with all strings type variables and enumerations. For example, `string greetings = "hi"` and call up `if (!textBox1.Text.Contains(greetings)) ...` It can also be used like this: `if (textBox1.Text != greetings) ...`

Comment: Oh so the last example
(textBox1.Text != greetings) would be if textBox1.Text IS NOT EQUAL TO greetings)

Comment: @ChristofferNilsson Precisely. The `.Contains` method does not require the _= sign_ because it is a boolean. All bools in if-statements can be called by simply their names if true. To call them if false, you add the ! in front of the name. If you are comparing to see if a property is not equal to another, hence using the _= sign_, then _!=_ is your friend.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining, very understandable and easy to follow! :D

Comment: @ChristofferNilsson No problem, you are a different coder everyday.